# Different pointers are equal?

Tags: pointers, go

I'm trying to represent some points on a 2d plane as pairs of integers. I want the points to be immutable (pass-by-value), but also for each to have a unique identity. To accomplish this, I made a struct with two `int`s and a `*string`. This works fine:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    s1 := ""
    s2 := ""
    p := Point{1,2,&s1}
    p2 := Point{1,2,&s2}
    fmt.Println(p2==p) // want false
}
type Point struct{X int; Y int; id *string}
```

```
$ go run a.go
false
```

Since the `string` isn't actually used for anything (I only care about telling whether two points are the same), it seems like the canonical solution for making a unique reference like this would be to use a pointer to `struct{}` instead:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    s1 := struct{}{}
    s2 := struct{}{}
    p := Point{1,2,&s1}
    p2 := Point{1,2,&s2}
    fmt.Println(p2==p) // want false
}
type Point struct{X int; Y int; id *struct{}}
```

However, now the two pointers are equal:

```
$ go run a.go
true
```

Why? Can this happen with strings as well? Should I use UUIDs instead?

Comment: Can you use an incrementing counter?  You'll have to guard the construction of these Points anyway, so rather than use an address, how about have the constructor shove in a counter and increment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The empty struct `struct{}{}` is special.

See: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees where it says:

> A struct or array type has size zero if it contains no fields (or
>   elements, respectively) that have a size greater than zero. Two
>   distinct zero-size variables may have the same address in memory.

You can probably just put a field in there to get uniqueness.  Something like:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type token struct{ bool }
type Point struct {
    X  int
    Y  int
    id *token
}

func main() {
    p := Point{1, 2, &token{}}
    p2 := Point{1, 2, &token{}}
    fmt.Println(p2 == p) // want false
}
```

Comment: What if two strings have zero-size? Can they have the same address?

Comment: @Dog: this is a slightly malformed question, since string values are not directly *addressible*, in the technical sense described in https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators.

If you have two variables to strings, you can address the variables.  By that definition, no, you would not get the same address even if both variables were set to empty strings: they're separate variables.  http://play.golang.org/p/ZYj-0T5Ytv

Comment: @Dog: put another way, you're storing pointers to [what's currently a two-word struct that references the actual string bytes](http://research.swtch.com/godata). Seems both too cute and less efficient to track identity by allocating these string headers and using their addresses as opposed to just getting an ID or some such.

Comment: @Dog: I'm getting curious: are you building an app that involves shattering glasses (or humans), users and admins, assigning floating-point constants to ints, etc., or are you just probing Go for interesting corner cases? :)

Comment: @twotwotwo less efficient maybe, but if you create points concurrently then you'll need a lock if you're using a counter, or an atomic integer. These questions aren't real code from my company

Comment: Yes; allocation itself occasionally has to synchronize for similar reasons (you could say it gives out "unique addresses"). If you're solving a problem and not just entertaining yourself by spending volunteer time, and you can't use `Point` addresses for identity, you can use a (buffered) channel giving out IDs, a lock, an atomic, or some exotic thing where goroutines allocate blocks of IDs atomically and give individual ones out without any synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

To distinguish between two different points, even if they have the same coordinates, use addresses. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Point struct {
    X int
    Y int
    p *Point
}

func NewPoint(x, y int) Point {
    p := Point{X: x, Y: y}
    p.p = &p
    return p
}

func main() {
    x, y := 1, 2
    p1 := NewPoint(x, y)
    p2 := NewPoint(x, y)
    fmt.Println(p1)
    fmt.Println(p2)
    fmt.Println(p1 == p1)
    fmt.Println(p1 == p2)
}
```

Output:

```
{1 2 0x10328000}
{1 2 0x10328020}
true
false
```