# Printing variables changes the previous code results

Tags: go, pointers

I have the following code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyStruct struct {
}

func main() {
    a := &MyStruct{}
    b := &MyStruct{}

    fmt.Println(a == b)
    fmt.Println(*a == *b)
}
```

Which as expected outputs

```
false
true
```

But, if I add two Print statements at the end like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyStruct struct {

}

func main() {
   a := &MyStruct{}
   b := &MyStruct{}

   fmt.Println(a == b)
   fmt.Println(*a == *b)
   fmt.Println(&a)
   fmt.Println(&b)
}
```

The output becomes something I did not expect:

```
true
true
0xc0000ae018
0xc0000ae020
```

Why does it become `true` in the first case?

Comment: This is only because you're using a **zero-sized struct** (it has no non-zero-sized fields). Two distinct a zero-sized structs (or two distinct zero-sized arrays) **MAY** have the same memory address, i.e. `a == b` MAY be true, it's not guaranteed, but it can happen. With non-zero struct this is guaranteed to never happen: https://go.dev/play/p/0i8DRmBwz1R

Comment: Go all the way to the bottom of the [spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec), it's literally the last paragraph.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378995/why-two-pointer-of-same-struct-which-only-used-new-function-for-creating-compare and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734504/different-pointers-are-equal and you're bound to find more if you search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Go language [specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> Pointers to distinct [zero-size](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees) variables may or may not be equal.

`MyStruct` is `struct{}`, which is a zero-size type. Hence, `a == b` may be `true` or `false`.